# how to update parent component from child component in angular2

Tags: angular, angular2-directives

I am looking for AngularJS ISolated(= operation) scope similar feature in Angular2.
I would like to change parent component value in child component, so that i don't need to use any EventEmitters.

**following is my code snippet.**

```
<component-1>
<div *ngFor="let row of listArray" >
    <component-2 [inputData]="row.inputData" (outputEvent)= "onComponentChange($event)"> </component-2>
</div>
<component-2 [inputData]="inputData2" (outputEvent)= "onComponentChange($event)"> </component-2>
<component-2 [inputData]="inputData3" (outputEvent)= "onComponentChange($event)"> </component-2>
<component-2 [inputData]="inputData4" (outputEvent)= "onComponentChange($event)"> </component-2>
```

```
@Component
component-1{
    onComponentChange(newValue){
        //where to keep the new value
        //this.inputData2/inputData3/inputData4/listArray[i].inputData ???????????
    }
}


@Component
component-2{
    @Input() inputData:string;
    @Output() outputEvent:EventEmitter<string>;
    changeComponentValue(newValue){
        this.outputEvent(newValue);
    }
}
```

I will change [inputData] value in component-2, that should reflect in component-1.
In existing @Output eventEmitter, I am unable to find which element value got changed.

Comment: You want to change the value? Or just want to know which element you are dealing with?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Here i'm showing you how to identify an **index** of an element that you are dealing with and how to assign new value to an element you are dealing with.

To assign a new value to **row.inputData** I'm dealing with TWO-WAY data binding with **@Input xxx**; and **@Output xxxChange** syntax.

To Identify **index** of an element you are dealing with I'm just using a new @output api.

observe this code calmly.

```
@Component({
  selector: 'my-app',
  directives:[ChildComponent],
  template:`<h1>My First Angular 2 App</h1>
  <div *ngFor="let row of listArray" >
  {{row.inputData}}
  <component-2 [(inputData)]="row.inputData" (outputEvent)= "onComponentChange($event)"> </component-2>
  </div>
   `
})
export class AppComponent { 
 title="Angular1";

 listArray=[{inputData:"micronyks"},{inputData:"micronyks1"},{inputData:"micronyks3"}];

 onComponentChange(value){
   console.log(value);
   this.listArray.forEach((item,index)=>{
     if(item.inputData==value){
       console.log(index);
     }
   })
 }
}
```

**component-2**

```
import { Component, Input,Output,EventEmitter } from '@angular/core';

@Component({
  selector: 'component-2',
  template:`<button (click)="changeComponentValue(inputData)">Click-{{inputData}}</button>`
})
export class ChildComponent { 
  @Input() inputData;
  @Output() outputEvent:EventEmitter<string>=new EventEmitter();
  @Output() inputDataChange=new EventEmitter();

  changeComponentValue(value){
        this.outputEvent.emit(value); //<---this will identify element index you are dealing with
        this.inputDataChange.emit("Angular2"); //<----new value will be assinged to an element that you are dealing with
    }
}
```

Working Demo : https://plnkr.co/edit/SqrfhtZZlSIsQE0Ko0oC?p=preview

Comment: thank you so much. This is what i am looking for, I no need to get row index. as long as it is changing parent value that is enough to me. I didn't under stand how  inputDataChange works, any way i will try to find it.   Thank you so much for your time.

Comment: Oh great. Good to know you like it.